# SELECT from union of tables with Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, union

I'm trying to do a CTAS (Create Table As Select) with Azure SQL. My first and foremost problem is I can't get to SELECT from the union of 2 tables. For instance:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table2]
)
```

returns a

> Incorrect syntax near ';'.
> error message.

Thanks in advance for any tip provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a table alias for the derived table:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1]
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table2]
     ) t
-------^
```

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Database does **not** support the `Create Table As (CTAS)` syntax.  Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools does support this syntax.

Confirm which type of database you are using by running `select @@version`.

If you are using Azure SQL DB, you can either use `SELECT ... INTO` which creates tables without indexes or simply do the table CREATE and INSERT into it as per normal.  A simple example:

```
SELECT *
INTO someTable
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table2]
) AS x
```

Comment: You're solving my secondary question, although my main interrogation was about the UNION (which I now understand required to be named with an alias, like in your answer).Thanks very much, yes I am using Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Seems like it's solved both questions.  Please consider marking it as the answer and/or upvoting mine or the other answers if they have proved useful.

Answer (score 1):

- Use CTE instead of a subquery but if you really want to do it like that then you need to always add a alias after each query

CODE 1: CTE

```
    With combined_data as (
    
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table2]
    )
    
    select * from combined_data
```

CODE2 : Subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table1]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table2]
) as combined_data
```